# how can i display image in UIscrollView which comes directly from parsing of web service?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want to display image in UIImageView which is on the UIScrollView and using Touch Event the image should change from Right-to-Left and Left-to-Right also.The images are the result of NSXml parsing so what should i do please help me in this task.what should i do and if possible then show me with some example.Thanks in Advance.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how you obtain the images.

If you get them as URLs, you need to download the actual images. There are examples of doing this.

If you get them as NSData (from downloading them or such), you just have to init a UIImage with the data, e.g. `[UIImage imageWithData:]` or `[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:]`.

Then you just do what everyone else does when adding an image to a scroll view. There are hundreds of examples. In short, add the image to a `UIImageView` then add that view to the scroll view using `addSubview:`.

Comment: i have got all Url in the array  and i display it in the UIScrollView but it shows one image less then the actual image.it don't show the First image if more then one image.

Comment: Have you checked if the URL for the first image is in the array or not? Show code snippet where you add the images to the scroll view.